# NSToolbar items hidden using xibs migrated on Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

We are using xib files to show a window + toolbar.
Compiling a Mac OS app with the latest Xcode (7 or 7.1) makes our toolbars items to be hidden for Yosemite 10.10.5, but it works fine on El Capitan.[image]

If I click the area, the actions are taken, so only the labels and images are hidden.

I have recreated the xib file from scratch with Xcode 7.1 but the issue is still there.

FYI: going back in our code history, before Xcode 7 was launched, and compiling the app without migrating xibs to Xcode 7 the issue is not reproducible.

Comment: Please embed the screenshot in the question so that people don't have to visit that crappy-app.com website.  Unless, of course, you are trying to drive traffic to that site?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was generated by a missing font which seems that broke the whole CoreText and that's generated the missing toolbar items. Really strange issue.